# Run a function everytime an input (whose name is defined in an array) is changed

Tags: javascript, arrays, input

I am trying to make it so that a warning is displayed when a user has unsaved settings on a page.

So far, I've added a JSON object to the page when it is loaded, and from there I've grabbed an array of the object keys.

Next up, I need to check if all of the options are the same as the settings specified in the JSON object (I assume I can do this with a loop) every time one of the settings is changed - what I don't know how to do is, from the array of keys that I have, run a JS function every time an input with one of those names is changed. Any suggestions welcome. Here is what I have so far (There are more than two options, just removed from here to save space).

JSON object -

```
var front_page_admin_args = {"image_type":"rotate","slideshow_pagination":null};
```

Making the array of keys -

```
var keys

try{ // Using Try/Catch as some older browsers do not support 'Object.keys()'
    keys = Object.keys(front_page_admin_args);
}
catch(err){
    var keys = $.map(front_page_admin_args, function(value, key){
        return key;
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at onchange? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onchange Also, are you using a JS framework such as jQuery?

Comment: Have you looked into knockout.js?THis seems like a perfect application of binding.

Comment: Yes, using jQuery. Investigating 'onchange' now... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code runs the given embedded function when any input on the page changes. Inside you can check whether this input is interesting for you.

```
var watchedKeys = ['email', 'password'];
$('input').change(function(e) {
  if (watchedKeys.indexOf(e.target.name) != -1) {
    alert(e.target.name + " has changed. new value:" + e.target.value);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, managed to suss it out from this. Just one note for anyone who picks this up in the future - `indexOf()` is not available in all browers (IE<9), so you'll need to account for that.